# An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy

Tags: spring, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy a Spring application to Google App Engine but getting the following error

```
12:27:48.714 [main] INFO com.titouanvanbelle.foodieserver.FoodieServerApplicationKt -- Starting FoodieServerApplicationKt using Java 17.0.7 with PID 1 (/workspace/foodie-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar started by www-data in /workspace)
12:27:48.728 [main] INFO com.titouanvanbelle.foodieserver.FoodieServerApplicationKt -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
12:27:50.759 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2023-06-13T12:28:41.971Z16116.fs.1:

12:27:50.834 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 54 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
12:27:53.376 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Starting...
12:27:53.780 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -- HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:5ef8e3f8-0166-4f9c-bf65-a7f7d8c6c56e user=SA
12:27:53.783 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
12:27:54.374 [main] INFO com.titouanvanbelle.foodieserver.FoodieServerApplicationKt -- Started FoodieServerApplicationKt in 6.45 seconds (process running for 9.46)
12:27:54.390 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
12:27:54.400 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

This is my configuration
**app.yaml**

```
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
... 
appengine {
    deploy {
        projectId = "foodie-XXXXX"
        version = "1"
        stopPreviousVersion = true
        promote = true
    }
}
```

The only reference to this error that I could find is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/troubleshooting?hl=fr#errors_when_deploying_to_an_existing_flexible_environment_version) but doesn't provide a solution.

Comment: Internal errors can occasionally be fixed by trying the deployment again. See if the error still occurs after redeploying your Spring application to Google App Engine. Contacting [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) is advised if you need help. Based on the details of your project and deployment settings, they can look into the internal problem and offer tailored advice.

Comment: I have tried deleting version on the Console and redeploying but the error persists. I'll try getting in touch with their support. Cheers